# How to use bootstrap-select in TypeScript with "noImplicitAny": true without getting bootstrap-select/index.d.ts is not a module

Tags: typescript, npm, node-modules, bootstrap-select

I am new at Typescript and I am trying to use bootstrap-select in a project that requests "noImplicitAny": true.

But I am not able to import BootstrapSelect from @types/bootstrap-select. The error is:

## **bootstrap-select/index.d.ts is not a module.**

I have tried a lot of things that I found on the internet, but so far no luck.
I tried to add  in the typescript file.
I tried to insert

```
"types" : ["bootstrap-select", "jquery"],
"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types/" ]
```

into the *tsconfig.json* but VSCode still complaining about the `index.d.ts` not been a module.

My import:

```
/// <reference types="bootstrap-select" />
import { BootstrapSelect } from 'bootstrap-select';
```

My tsconfig.json:

[image]

My package.json:

[image]

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should install "bootstrap-select", not just "@types/bootstrap-select".
run
`npm install bootstrap-select --save`
It's should work for you.

Comment: Grechko I have done that already. `Look at devDependencies`.

Comment: Why devDependencies? I think it should be into dependencies

Comment: Exactly. devDependencies are for development, while dependencies are for runtime. The import is in the wrong place.

Comment: But it does not work even in dev, where my current problem is.